# Turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Functions for my App. I installed these firebase functions on my PC but I can't use the following command:

> Firebase deploy --only functions

I get the following error:

```
node_modules/google-gax/build/protos/iam_service.d.ts:17:23 - error TS2497: This module 
can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 
'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.

17 import * as Long from 'long';
                       ~~~~~~

node_modules/google-gax/build/protos/operations.d.ts:17:23 - error TS2497: This module 
can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 
'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.

17 import * as Long from 'long';
                         ~~~~~~

Found 2 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
 1  node_modules/google-gax/build/protos/iam_service.d.ts:17
 1  node_modules/google-gax/build/protos/operations.d.ts:17

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Does anyone know how to turn on this flag?

Comment: Firebase employee here. I noticed the same break in the firebase-functions integration tests. I've followed up with the repo maintainers for google-gax and we'll hopefully have a fix out soon.

Comment: The fix should now be live. Let us know if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just add `"skipLibCheck": true` to your `tsconfig.json` as shown below:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
```

Comment: This may resolve the issue experienced by the OP (since it seems to be doing compiler checks in libraries and that is unlikely to be something most people want), but it is not the same thing as turning on `esModuleInterop`.  For more information on the flag itself (which would be set in the same place, `compilerOptions`), check out [TypeScript's docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop)

Comment: This should be unnecessary. google-gax sent out a patch to fix the issue.